# When a user clicks on a link, how can I send a php variable to that new page

Tags: php, html

What I am trying to do is:

- a user as a list of venues to click on from a table (loaded From sql)
- When they click on a venue the user is sent to venuePage.php
- What I need is the primary key of the venue the have clicked on.

I have tried using $session variables but so far no luck. here is my code:

```
   <td id="startingAt"> <a href="clubPage.php"
  onClick="<?php $_SESSION['currentVenueId'] = $venueID;?>"> 

  <p> <?php echo $venue; ?> </p> </a> </td>
```

Currently I am just echoing out `$_SESSION['currentVenueId']` and the result does not update.

Any help would be really appreciated! Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this:

```
   <td id="startingAt"> <a href="clubPage.php">
```

=>

```
   <td id="startingAt"> <a href="clubPage.php?venueID=<?php $_SESSION['currentVenueId'] = $venueID;?>">
```

And in the clubPage.php you could get the value with `$venueId = $_GET['venueId']`

Comment: This will throw an error if `$_GET['venueId']` is not defined. (I.e. if a user visits clubPage.php with no query string).

Comment: I hope he is aware how to use `$_GET`. If I would do everything for him - what is he supposed to do?! If not, he will ask again, it's just a hint, how to use it ...

Answer (score 0):

Using [`$_GET`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php) you can simply put your variable within the URL:

```php
<a href="clubPage.php?currentVenueId=<?php echo $venueId; ?>">...</a>
```

Then pull it using:

```
if ( isset($_GET['currentVenueId']) )
    $venueId = $_GET['currentVenueId'];
```

If you have more than one variable, you can combine them with an ampersand.

Comment: Hey Thank you for your reply.. I am a bit of a novis when it comes to this. When it comes to the variables am I still to put $ sign? so <a href="clubPage.php?$venueId=$currentVenueId ?

Comment: @Jordanbaggs what do you mean? This is an example URL with GET-able data: `http://example.com?foo=bar`; you'd pull the "bar" data by using `$_GET['foo']`.

Comment: Sorry my code still doesnt work so far I have <a href="clubPage.php?clubId=<?php $Starting_At_ID?>"> and im getting it by $clubId = $_GET['clubID']; Am I doing it wrong?

Comment: You have to use `echo`: `...<?php echo $Starting_At_ID; ?>...`. :)

Comment: `$clubId = $_GET['clubID'];`is wrong, if this is your link: `<a href="clubPage.php?clubId=<?php $Starting_At_ID?>">` , you need to use this: `$clubId = $_GET['clubId'];` and then you can `echo $clubId;` (the d...) James, your answer is also wrong!

Comment: @JamesDonnelly because there is not variable `$Staring_At_ID` in `clubPage.php`, the variable is in the current Page. What you wanted to say is: `...<?php echo $clubId; ?>...`

Comment: @Haudegen this is what Jordan posted in the comment above mine. This is also a comment and not my answer. My answer remains unchanged.

Comment: Oh damn!!

In meant JordanBaggs! Not you, sorry James, your answer is correct!!

Please forgive me :-)

Comment: @Haudegen no worries. :)